# what is the mpv option mean in Node?

Tags: node.js, npm

I wanted to use mpv option for my Node project, but it seems the option is reserved already.

> $ npm --mpv
>
> output : 6.5.0

what's the mpv option pointing?

and is there any way I can use the mpv option for my Node project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TLDR

You can use `--mpv` as an argument to your node.js project. There is nothing that would make it not work.

#### Example:

```
// example.js
if (process.argv[2] == '--mpv') {
  console.log('hooray');
}
```

The script above would print `hooray` if you run it with `--mpv` as argument:

```
$ node example.js --mpv
hooray
```

---

#### Details:

The `npm` command treats `--` options the same as `-` options for some reason. Thus the command:

```
npm --mpv
```

is somehow interpreted as

```
npm -m -p -v
```

Neither `m` nor `p` does anything and are ignored instead of throwing errors. But the `v` option prints out the version number. Thus the command is the same as

```
npm -v
```

---

Note that `npm` is not `node.js`. Node does not behave the same and would throw an error:

```
$ node --mpv
node: bad option: --mpv
```

Indeed, the `npm` project explicitly declares themselves to not be a node package manager even though `npm` is now managed by the node.js project directly. Npm can deploy packages written in other languages such as Ruby (such as the original Sass project, now re-written in js), Python or even C and assembly.

Comment: I can do with --env options which might be -e -n -v, do you know how different between mpv and env?

Comment: Investigating it further I see that `--env` doesn't work but `--nv` works printing the version number. Going with my gut feeling, I looked at npm command documentation and it looks like there are commands that begin with `e`: `edit` and `explore`. Since there are no commands that begin with `f` I tried `--fnv` and it works printing the version. So it seems to be just how npm parses its arguments. `--fjkmnqxyzv` should work because it contains all the letters that does not start a valid command except `v`

Comment: .. TLDR - you shouldn't really worry about this because it does not matter. You should not pass arguments to npm run scripts such as `start`. Instead define the arguments in your package.json file. For node.js apps in general you don't need to worry about this because npm is not involved

Comment: Note that in case it is not clear - you can use --mpv option in your node project. It is not reserved. What you see npm doing is just a side-effect of how it parses arguments.

Comment: I really appreciate for the investigation and your time! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`--mpv` is not a reserved option -- nor is any other sequence.  node itself takes [many options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html), but anything on the command line after your script name is passed directly to `process.argv`.

In other words, the following have two different behaviors:

```bash
$ node --inspect script.js # enables node's built-in debugger; process.argv = ['node', 'script.js']
$ node script.js --inspect # process.argv = ['node', 'script.js', '--inspect']
```

Also, `--mpv` [does not appear](https://www.google.com/search?q=mpv+site%3Adocs.npmjs.com) anywhere in the npm documentation.  I suspect that the npm CLI is misinterperting `--mpv` as `-v` and printing its version number.

Comment: you are right, the version was my npm version. is there any way I can use the mpv option, so that I can get the option value using process.evn.npm_config_mpv?

Comment: Why are you using npm instead of node directly?